# Why is getting an Azure AD token via "acquire_token_with_username_password" failing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure-active-directory

When I try to authenticate myself and get a token from Azure AD using the "acquire_token_with_username_password" method, I get the following error:

> *The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret'.*

I am passing the client ID in.  I read in some other posts that the problem may be that the application should be registered as a "native" app and not a web app, but that posting was 2 years ago and I don't see anywhere on the app properties in Azure to specify it is a native app.  I am passing in the IDs in variables via the call:

```
 token = auth_context.acquire_token_with_username_password(resource, username, password, clientId)
```

and I don't see anywhere in the "acquire_token_with_username_password" where I would pass a client_assertion or client_secret, not to mention I'm not sure what I would put there.

Comment: Which grant_type you are requesting with? Are you following any official document?

Comment: I took an example application for authenticating from Microsoft.  The "acquire_token_with_username_password" specification does not have a parameter for specifying a grant_type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if the AD App is a `Web` type, the 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret' is required, just follow the screenshot to set the AD App to public client, i.e. native app, then it will work.

[image]

Comment: So, I did set that and got further, but now get:

"AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID ..."

Comment: @GregH Your user account is not in the same tenant with the application?

Comment: @GregH Actually, the sdk `acquire_token_with_username_password` essentially uses the [azure ad ROPC flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc),  If your app is a multi-tenant app in tenant1, and you want to use the user account in tenant2 to get the access token, then the app need to be consent by the admin of tenant2 first, to fix this, use the admin account to request the consent url, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/grant-admin-consent#construct-the-url-for-granting-tenant-wide-admin-consent

Comment: @GregH After consent the app, you should be able to get the token with the normal user account.